# Dynamic Input fields on selectChange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add dynamic inputs on select change and i am following below approaches:

> Approach 1

```
<select name="ex" id="ex1w"><option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>.. upto 10</select>

<div id="dynamic"></div>

<-------- JS --------->
<script>
 $(function(){
    $('#ex1w').on('change', function() {
        var tsd = ( this.value );
        $("div#dynct").empty();
        for(var j=0; j < tsd; j++) 
        $("div#dynct").append('<div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-
        bottom:20px"><label for="' + (j++) + '">Child Category '+(j++) 
        +'</label><input name="name_ct' + (j++) + '" id="id_ct' + (j++) 
        + '" type="text" class="childcat form-control" placeholder="Add 
        Child Category" ></div>');
    });
 });
</script>
```

**This approach is working fine to add inputs but errors comes as `b is undefined` while using jQueryValidation plugin 1.14.0**

> Second Approach

```
<!-- Same Select Box of 10 values -->
```

Now instead of creating inputs by JS, i tried HTML approach to mention all divs like as below

```
<div class="dyn" id="dyn1">
  <input type="text" name="dynpu1" id="dynpu1" />
</div> <!-- same upto 10 divs `dyn10` -->

<!-- JS -->
 $('#ex1w').on('change', function() {
        var tsd = ( this.value );
        for(var i=1; i <= tsd; i++) {  $('div#dyn'+i).show(); }
 });
```

This approach is behaving strange as suppose if i have

1. Choosen value as 3 and then 3 inputs are shown (which is correct)
2. But now if i change to lower value say 2 then 3 inputs are shown, those are not reducing to 2.

Any solutions please to any of the problems.

Comment: If you are downvoting then mention reason pl. It is not professional..

Comment: Thanks for upvote.. dont know why people downvote without reason